# Overlaying Legend in Map Plot Covers Plot

Tags: r, plot, r-package

I am attempting to create a plot using the `map` library. However, the legend always seems to be covering the map, while I would like it to be off to the side so the plot is visible. Here is the code that generates the map in question:

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
map(database = "county", region = "Michigan")
legend("center", c("Legend 1","Legend 2"), horiz = FALSE)
```

And here is the image generated (with the legend obscuring the plot).

[image: Legend covering plot]

Any ideas on how to move the legend over? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps use the `x` and `y` parameters to numerically position it vs rely on the keyword shortcuts for `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the x and y parameters for the legend.  In this case one could specify the lat and long of where you would like to place the legend or use the default positions:
"bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right" and "center"

Example:

```
legend( c("Legend 1","Legend 2"), x="bottomleft")
```

or specify the x and y coordinates (with the latitude and longitude).  For the state of Michigan:

```
legend( c("Legend 1","Legend 2"), x=-90, y=43)
```

If the legend is still not in correct location, consider manually setting the plotting limits for the chart:

```
map(database = "county", region = "Michigan", xlim=c(-91, -82))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the example provided, the legend is still obscuring the plot. Furthermore, it appears that replacing the ```x``` variable with just ``x = 10`` or something to that effect doesn't have the legend appear at all.